# how to route iPhone audio to the bluetooth speaker

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I am trying to get input from Mic and output it to my bluetooth device ti Speaker using `audioRouteOverride`. But No luck. iPhone Mic output is still going to iPhone builtin speakers. I expected `kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BluetoothA2DP` is the key here. But it is not working as expected.

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    OSStatus status;

    // Describe audio component
    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    // Get component
    AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    // Get audio units
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &audioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);

    // Enable IO for recording
    UInt32 flag = 1;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              kInputBus,
                              &flag, 
                              sizeof(flag));
    checkStatus(status);

    // Enable IO for playback
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              kOutputBus,
                              &flag, 
                              sizeof(flag));
    checkStatus(status);

    // Describe format
    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.00;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2;

    // Apply format
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              kInputBus, 
                              &audioFormat, 
                              sizeof(audioFormat));
    checkStatus(status);
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              kOutputBus, 
                              &audioFormat, 
                              sizeof(audioFormat));
    checkStatus(status);


    // Set input callback
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                              kInputBus, 
                              &callbackStruct, 
                              sizeof(callbackStruct));
    checkStatus(status);

    // Set output callback
    callbackStruct.inputProc = playbackCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                              kOutputBus,
                              &callbackStruct, 
                              sizeof(callbackStruct));
    checkStatus(status);

    // Disable buffer allocation for the recorder (optional - do this if we want to pass in our own)
    flag = 0;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              kInputBus,
                              &flag, 
                              sizeof(flag));

    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)status);
    // Allocate our own buffers (1 channel, 16 bits per sample, thus 16 bits per frame, thus 2 bytes per frame).
    // Practice learns the buffers used contain 512 frames, if this changes it will be fixed in processAudio.
    tempBuffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    tempBuffer.mDataByteSize = 512 * 2;
    tempBuffer.mData = malloc( 512 * 2 );

    UInt32 audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    status = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(audioCategory), &audioCategory);
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)status);


    UInt32 allowMixing = true;
    status = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);

    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BluetoothA2DP; //kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);

    status = AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Hey, do you any solution for this problem? I am facing issue for Bluetooth.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this problem. I am trying to achieve the same requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code. This code is also working on iOS 7 and 8(tested).

```
+ (void) startBTAudio
{
    UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput, sizeof(allowBluetoothInput), &allowBluetoothInput);  
}


+ (void) stopBTAudio
{
    UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 0;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput, sizeof(allowBluetoothInput), &allowBluetoothInput);
}
```

Comment: This code don't work for Bluetooth speaker. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Do you got the solution ?